# How to scroll browser view port to top of page after an ajax submit?

Tags: jquery

I have an upload form -- after the user submits the form, I'd like to scroll the window back to the top of the page (where I display some help text).  How do I correctly scroll the window back to the top of the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the scroll method on the window object to do this:

```
window.scroll(0,0)
```

The arguments are the horizontal and vertical measure of scrolling within the window, so 0,0 brings it back to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you could try the [ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), which is highly customizable.

Comment: a similar and simpler plugin http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use the .focus() event on some tag at the top of the page?

```
$("input#myFirstName").focus();
```

Comment: Unless it is on the very top of the page.. but if you have, let's say, 20px margin on the top this approach would not work well